# How to write a query to get data and skip 4 first letters on special records in sql

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have problem to read data from database. Could someone help me to write a suitable query for my purpose?

```
Select name1, name2 
   if (name2 start with "abcd" or "bcda" or "dasd" then skip 4 first Characters )
From TableName 
where name2 like 'Input'
```

Lets have a glimpse of question : I want to get data of name2. Data that are similar to  'Input' but at the first I want to check if name2 started with "abcd" then I don't want to show 4 first Characters of name2 .

Edited : I forgot I should check 2 different parameters then I add an or to it and also I am working on an app for android and  use SQlite.

I hope I could explain it clearly and at the sorry for my English .

Edit 2 : I have problem yet with code . It doesn't show 4 first letters very well  but problem is here it returns this 4 first letters . This code is search part of word dictionary . I attached a picture to make it clear for you . [all of these words started with 'das ' and I don't want to show them because I filtered it with below code .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vjS5.jpg)

```
c = mydb.rawQuery("select dId, case when substr(dWord, 1, 4) in ('das ', 'der ','die ') then substr(dWord, 5, length(dWord) - 4)else dWord end as dWord from german where dWord like '%"+search+"%'",null);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results are helpful, especially if English is not your first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RDMBS supports a regexp function like `regex_replace()`, that's straightforward:

```
regexp_replace(name2, '^(abcd)|(bcda)', '') as name2
```

This will work on Oracle, Postgres, MySQL 8.0, PrestoDB, BigQuery, DB2, Sybase (and probably more that I am not thinking of right now!).

---

In SQLIte, you can use string functions and a case expression:

```
select 
    name1,
    case when substr(name2, 1, 4) in ('abcd', 'bcda')
        then substr(name2, 5, length(name2) - 4) 
        else name2
    end as name2
from mytable
where name2 = 'input'
```

Note: `name2 like 'input'` is equivalent to `name2 = 'input'`, since no wildcard comes into play.

Comment: @Hogan: added! Thanks

Comment: thanks for your response , I am using sqlite and I don't know it support regex_replace() . As I am novice I need complete code :(

Comment: @Shayegan: I added a solution for sqlite in my answer.

Comment: Can I write all code in one line ? And also I added 2 more parameters for check ( 2 or ). how it can be ? Thanks

Comment: @Shayegan: yes you can format the code as you wish, this has no impact on the syntax.

Comment: with name2 like 'input' it is work very well . Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you check my problem please ?
Thanks

Comment: @Shayegan: it is not a good practice to substantially modify a question *after* answer were posted. I can only suggest that you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Also I cannot understand why you unaccepted this answer, since it does answer your *original* question.

Comment: sorry for that . I am new here and I don't know how it works . I thought if I unaccepted answer maybe some one answer it again and with accepted question nobody answer it  . I don't changed my question at all the problem was I didn't know how I can explain it at first  . I will ask a new question .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how to code what you ask.

```
Select name1, name2, 
  case when left(name2,4) = 'abcd' 
       then substring(name2,4) 
       else name2 
  end as name2
From TableName 
where name2 like 'Input'
```

Comment: Your `case` clause can also be coded as `iif(left(name2) = 'abcd', substring(name2, 4), name2)` in MS T-SQL.

Comment: @DavidRTribble -- true -- I was trying to use standard sql if possible.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks for your response but I couldn't get data with this query on sqlite . Also I edited my question could you check it again ?

Comment: @Hogan Could you help me to solve this problem? I edited question and add new info . thanks

Comment: err how did it change -- just sqlite? @Shayegan?

Comment: (1) `left()` does not exist in sqlite (2) In other RDBMS, you would assume that a second argument is needed for this to make sense: `left(name2) = 'abcd'`